# Add element to share dialog

Tags: windows, sdk, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

It it possible to add custom element to [`Share data`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt243293.aspx) dialog?

When I sent a text to it I want to add custom actions inside my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible to add anything to the dialog.

you have to add the custom actions before you do the actual sharing then inside your own app.